# json format in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to assemble a string in JSON format with Firebase information. This I can do, but the string structure goes wrong, I get:

```
[
  '7801',
  {
    keycode: '111111',
    dataStatus: 'Test1'
  },
  '7802',
  {
    keycode: '222222',
    dataStatus: 'Test2'
  }
]
```

But it should be:

```
{
  '7801':
  {
    keycode: '111111',
    dataStatus: 'Test1'
  },
  '7802':
  {
    keycode: '222222',
    dataStatus: 'Test2'
  }
}
```

My code:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const serviceAccount = require('./firestore/firestoreTeste.json');
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});

const db = admin.firestore();

let results = [];
let documents = db.collection('place2').get()
    .then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            var namePlace;
            namePlace = doc.id.toString();
            let subCollectionDocs = db.collection('place2').doc(doc.id).collection("locals").get()
                .then(snapshot => {
                    results = []
                    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                        results.push(doc.id, doc.data());

                    })
                    console.log(results);
                }).catch(err => {
                    console.log("Error subcolection", err);
                })
        });
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log("Error documents", err);
    });
```

I am a beginner in JS and I cannot change this structure.

Does anyone know what I should do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `results` as an Object, which seems to be what you actually want to do:

```
let results = {};
```

Then, instead of `push()`ing the results into the Array structure, create a key and an associated value in `results`:

```
results[doc.id] = doc.data();
```

Further reading:

- [Object - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)
- [Property accessors#Bracket notation - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation)